# Occurs in MYOB Accounting Plus 18.5 among other versions. Cannot get the function address for " MAPISendMail" from "MAPI32.dll"

Tags: windows, email, mapi, myob

I've installed MYOB on SBS server 2003.  Why?  Because the users were using offline files and it turned out there was about 7 versions of the file both locally and on the server that were out of sync. So the only way I could control the file access was to force RDP to the server. Always using the server file and always in sync.

Anyway, this issue occurs in MYOB Accounting Plus 18.5.

`Cannot get the function address for "MAPISendMail" from "MAPI32.dll" Please check your Mapi installation`

I just want to send mail from MYOB but I can't - MYOB support is useless and blames everyone else...(i.e. Microsoft and outlook)

I have found other people with the same problem whose resolution appears to be to copy MAPI32.dll into myob directory but that hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

MYOB uses your current instance of Outlook to send emails out.

so on the server you need to have outlook 2003/2007 installed and configured with a user account for it to function properly.

BTW, your setup is typical in multi user environment.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when outlook has been set up for exchange, it's not a user account error (if it's because there's no default account another error will be generated instead of this one). it's because MAPI32.dll for an outlook set up for an exchange server is different from a normal outlook MAPI32.dll, causing MYOB to fail in accessing the "MAPISendMail" function correctly.

You need to copy MAPI32.dll (located in the Windows/system32/ folder) from ANOTHER computer, probably one of your local computers that does NOT have an exchange server set up (an outlook configured to receive mail from an exchange server is okay, just as long as an exchange server itself isn't configured on that computer) and paste it into your MYOB directory (e.g. C:/Premier19/). That should solve your problem.

It took me ages to figure out the solution, and as far as my research went I couldn't find it anywhere on the internet, so I just thought I'd post it here since it's pretty much the first page that comes up in google when you search the error.